# matching rows and fields from two files

Tags: awk

I would like to match the record number in one file will the same field number in another file:

file1:

```
1
3
5
4
3
1
5
```

file2:

```
A B C D E F G
H I J J K L M
N O P Q R S T
```

I would like to use the record numbers corresponding to `5` in the first file to obtain the corresponding fields in the second file. Desired output:

```
C G
J M
P T
```

So far, I've done:

```
awk '{ if ($1=="5") print NR }' file1 > temp
for i in $(cat temp); do
    awk '{ print $"'${i}'" }' file2
done
```

But get the output:

```
C
J
P
G
M
T
```

I would like to have this in the format of the desired output above, but can't get it to work. Perhaps using `prinf` or `awk` for-loop might work, but I have had no success.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{if($1==5)a[NR];next}{for(i in a){printf $i" "}print ""}' a b
C G
J M
P T
```